# Creating a big matrix where every element is the same

Tags: python, matrix, sage

I'm trying to create a matrix of dimension `nxn` in Sage. But every element in the matrix has to be `1/n`. The size of n is around 7000.

First I tried using creating a matrix of ones with the build in sagemethod, and then multiplying the matrix with `1/n`. This is very slow and crashes my jupyter notebook kernel.

`T  =matrix.ones(7000) * 1/n`

A second thing I tried is creating all the elements by list comprehension.

`T = matrix(RDF,[[1/l for x in range(l)] for row in range(l)])`

This also seems to be something my pc can't handle.

Comment: What kind of matrix is this? Are you referring to `np.matrix`? Also, you refer to `n` and `N`. Are they the same?

Comment: @gmds based on the tags, it appears to be a [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) matrix.

Comment: Big N and small n is the same. I edited my question. It's a Sage matrix as Karl said.

Comment: Use the callable argument option to the constructor, and make it a lambda function that returns a constant. See [General Matrix Constructor](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/constructor.html)

Comment: @JamesKPolk that works! Thanks!

Comment: I think part of the problem with some of your other options was that you are using true rationals, not floats/doubles, in both cases.  In the second example it might not seem that way, but the list comprehension is all rationals before `RDF` gets applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JamesKPolk gave me a working solution.

`T = matrix(RDF, 6000, 6000, lambda i,j: 1/6000)`

Answer (score 0):

what about using zeros and adding a no what you want to array 
for e.g. if N=7000

then:

```
import numpy as np
N=7000
temp_array = np.zeros((N,N))
main_array = (1/N) + temp_array
print(main_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do a all zero-matrix,
like this:

```
matrix(3,2)
```

which will return
Note: **Treat all parentheses as one long**

```
(0  0)
(0  0)
(0  0)
```